# Issue with Subprocess and popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Recently , i wrote the following code to run a python file 'file1.py' from another python code. I am working on raspberry pi (with raspian )

Python code:

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.Popen(['python','./file1.py'])
    print 'Done'
```

Output:

```
    Done
```

file1.py does not executed,No other response on screen

**file1.py**

```
    a=5
    a=a+5
    print(a)
```

I have searched for the somewhat same question ,but it's not working for me. Please help!

[Running multiple Python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163962/running-multiple-python-scripts)

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess.Popen()` to run the other script? Can you not just import and run it normally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python getoutput() equivalent in subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657690/python-getoutput-equivalent-in-subprocess)

Comment: Hi @amratansh-gupta, why don't you use a shebang inside of the file `file1.py`?

Comment: what happens if you replace `subprocess.Popen` with `subprocess.check_call`?

Answer (score 1):

`Popen` forks the current process, which means you won't see its output simply by printing in the executed script.

You will need to redirect its output:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python','./file1.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's working. However if my file1.py needs input values from the user , in that case how can i modify this so that i will be able to input the required data?

Answer (score 0):

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["python","1st.py"],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

OR

```
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Communicate() will retrieve the last processed process output that will help to see the results