# Running multiple python scripts in a sequence

Tags: python

I have scripts I would like to execute in sequence with a time delay between the each of them.

The intention is to run the scripts which scan for an string in file names and imports those files into a folder. The time delay is to give the script the time to finish copying the files before moving to the next file.

I have tried the questions already posed on Stackoverflow:

> [Running multiple Python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163962/running-multiple-python-scripts)
>
> [Run a python script from another python script, passing in args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args)

But I'm not understanding why the lines below don't work.

```
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.call(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\get summary into folder.py', shell=True)
time.sleep(100)
subprocess.call(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\get summaries into folder.py', shell=True)
time.sleep(100)
```

The script opens the files but doesn't run.

Comment: You have to call it the same  way you initialize python from the command line. `py C:\Users\User\Documents\get summary into folder.py` (or the `python` command depending on how you have it configured.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things, first of all, [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) accepts seconds as an argument, so you're waiting 100s after you've spawned these 2 processes, I guess you meant `.100`. Anyway, if you just want to run synchronously your 2 scripts better use [subprocess.Popen.wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), that way you won't have to wait more than necessary, example below:

```
import time
import subprocess

test_cmd = "".join([
    "import time;",
    "print('starting script{}...');",
    "time.sleep(1);",
    "print('script{} done.')"
])

for i in range(2):
    subprocess.Popen(
        ["python", "-c", test_cmd.format(*[str(i)] * 2)], shell=True).wait()
    print('-'*80)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I am a bit of a newbie though; where do the file destinations go in your example?